# getting "Failed to create meeting error 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings"

Tags: python, django, django-views, zoom-sdk

I have added the client id and secrete key and if i am autharizing the app from postman its working but as soon as i tried to ping the api with my app it giving 401 error.

how can i authorize my app into zoom app and can create meeting with dynamic token

```
                authrization_url = 'https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize'
                authrization_params = {
                    'client_id': zoom_client_key,
                    'response_type': 'code',
                    'redirect_uri': 'https://gensproject.supporthives.com/zoom',
                }   
                auth_response = requests.post(authrization_url, data=authrization_params)

                if auth_response:


                    # Obtain a new access token
                    access_token_url = 'https://zoom.us/oauth/token'
                    access_token_params = {
                        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                        'client_id': zoom_client_key,
                        'client_secret': zoom_client_secret,
                    }

                    try:
                        response = requests.post(access_token_url, data=access_token_params)
                        response.raise_for_status()
                        access_token = response.json().get('access_token', '')
                    except requests.RequestException as e:
                        return Response({'message': 'Failed to obtain access token', 'error': str(e)}, status=500)


                    # Create a Zoom meeting

                    # user_id = "ops@supporthives.com"
                    # create_meeting_url = f"https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/{user_id}/meetings"

                    "https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?client_id=MeGkVnUrQGG15c7ESPP1ZA&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgensproject.supporthives.com%2Fzoom"

                    create_meeting_url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings'
                    create_meeting_headers = {
                        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
                        # 'Authorization': f'Bearer eyJzdiI6IjAwMDAwMSIsImFsZyI6IkhTNTEyIiwidiI6IjIuMCIsImtpZCI6IjQ0NTYzNTg5LTA0YzAtNDY1ZC05NjBhLTljM2Y4YmI1ZjRmMyJ9.eyJ2ZXIiOjksImF1aWQiOiJiOTg4ZGQ4ZGNiYmQ0NTcyMjM0OWU4ZWE1ZGQ5NTVkMCIsImNvZGUiOiJ6V0tvUWhBREtuQWRHdVVuRkt5Uk15WXF2TjBYaXpDa0EiLCJpc3MiOiJ6bTpjaWQ6TWVHa1ZuVXJRR0cxNWM3RVNQUDFaQSIsImdubyI6MCwidHlwZSI6MCwidGlkIjowLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL29hdXRoLnpvb20udXMiLCJ1aWQiOiI3RkRIdW16TFNMZW5xUVk0cDRFNDRnIiwibmJmIjoxNzExNDUyMTk0LCJleHAiOjE3MTE0NTU3OTQsImlhdCI6MTcxMTQ1MjE5NCwiYWlkIjoiMVpmNnBDYkRROHF2emU1RFB0VnQ0USJ9.2oTMkSwL0OrnOAswTJoscy8zOSJhVmplTHsE6gh3H5-z_7sznAanBF2XyL3wO9FLGpggsFSqWxB04MXQof7YDw',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }

                    

                    event_datetime = datetime.combine(event.event_date, datetime.min.time())
                    start_time_utc = mktime(event_datetime.utctimetuple())

                    create_meeting_params = {
                        'topic': event.event_title,
                        'type': 2,  # Scheduled meeting
                        'start_time': f'{start_time_utc}000',
                        'duration': 60,
                        'timezone': 'UTC',
                        'description': event.event_description,
                        'settings': {
                            'host_video': True,
                            'participant_video': True,
                            'waiting_room': False,
                            'join_before_host': True,
                            'mute_upon_entry': False,
                            'auto_recording': 'none',
                        },
                    }
                    

                    try:
                        create_meeting_response = requests.post(create_meeting_url, headers=create_meeting_headers, json=create_meeting_params)
                        create_meeting_response.raise_for_status()
                        meeting_link = create_meeting_response.json().get('join_url', '')
                        event.event_link = meeting_link
                        event.event_meeting_data = create_meeting_response.json()
                        event.save()
                        # return success(201, meeting_link, "Meeting created successfully")
                    except requests.RequestException as e:
                        return fail(500 ,'Failed to create meeting error ' + str(e))
                
                else:
                    return fail(400,"Zoom App not autharized!")
```

here is my code in which i am geting error again and again

how can i authorize this app. what will be correct way to generate meeting link dynamically.

Comment: Your OAuth authorization code flow begins with a user being redirected to Zoom's authorization URL. This should not be a POST request, it is typically a GET request that the user's browser will follow afterwards

Comment: Actually I have used the get request but still it won't work every time same error

Answer (score 0):

It is an OAuth flow and is used to authorize apps with Zoom and create a meeting afterwards

I will create two views for you in Django. I looked at the [examples in the official documentation](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/integrations/oauth/)

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('authorize/', views.authorize, name='authorize'),
    path('zoom/callback/', views.zoom_callback, name='zoom_callback'),
]
```

Put these in your settings.py:

```
ZOOM_CLIENT_ID = 'Client id'
ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET = 'Client secret'
```

and here, I created two views, one for authorization:

```
def authorize(request):
    authorization_url = 'https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize'
    redirect_uri = 'https://gensproject.supporthives.com/zoom/callback'
    return redirect(f"{authorization_url}?response_type=code&client_id={settings.ZOOM_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}")
```

and another is for the callback (I copied your code for the create meeting part):

```
def zoom_callback(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    if not code:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'No code provided by Zoom'}, status=400)

    access_token_url = 'https://zoom.us/oauth/token'
    authorization = base64.b64encode(f"{settings.ZOOM_CLIENT_ID}:{settings.ZOOM_CLIENT_SECRET}".encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    access_token_headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Basic {authorization}'
    }
    access_token_params = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': 'https://gensproject.supporthives.com/zoom/callback'
    }
    response = requests.post(access_token_url, headers=access_token_headers, params=access_token_params)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Failed to obtain access token'}, status=500)
    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')

    # then you can use access token here afterwards to create a Zoom meeting

    create_meeting_url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings'
    create_meeting_headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    event_datetime = datetime.combine(event.event_date, datetime.min.time())
    start_time_utc = mktime(event_datetime.utctimetuple())

    create_meeting_params = {
                    'topic': event.event_title,
                    'type': 2,  # Scheduled meeting
                    'start_time': f'{start_time_utc}000',
                    'duration': 60,
                    'timezone': 'UTC',
                    'description': event.event_description,
                    'settings': {
                        'host_video': True,
                        'participant_video': True,
                        'waiting_room': False,
                        'join_before_host': True,
                        'mute_upon_entry': False,
                        'auto_recording': 'none',
                    },
                }
                

    try:
        create_meeting_response = requests.post(create_meeting_url, headers=create_meeting_headers, json=create_meeting_params)
        create_meeting_response.raise_for_status()
        meeting_link = create_meeting_response.json().get('join_url', '')
        event.event_link = meeting_link
        event.event_meeting_data = create_meeting_response.json()
        event.save()
        # return success(201, meeting_link, "Meeting created successfully")
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        return fail(500 ,'Failed to create meeting error ' + str(e))
```

Comment: its not working i am not getting code using "GET" where by pasting the url i am getting code in browswe